# Scope records a user has purchased

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope, associations

This is my setup:

- users have many purchases
- packs have many purchases
- packs have many recipes

I want to select all recipes a user has bought with a scope in the `Recipe` class. This is what I have as of now:

```
scope :purchased, lambda { |user| includes(pack: :purchases).where(packs: { purchases: { user: user } }) }
```

Because of some reason when I call `Recipe.purchased(current_user)` I get all `Recipe` records.

What am I doing wrong with the scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done easily in Rails. You just use [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) with the `:through` option like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :packs, through: :purchases
  has_many :recipes, through: :packs
end

user = User.first
user.recipes # returns all user's recipes
```